# PHP equal strings do not match

Tags: php, html, sql

As the title says, I am trying to compare "codes" that are unused in my database to an input textfield. However, even if both are equal, they do not match. I will explain the problem further below:

SQL (PromoCode.php):

```
public function SelectPromoCode($db) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    "   SELECT *
        FROM `promocode_3`
        WHERE used = 0
        ");

  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $rows;
}
```

This simply selects only the unused codes in my database (where used = 0)

[image: table]

Here is where the user attempts to enter the code (name = redeem)

[image: enter]

Now here is the file where the comparison between the database and the user input occurs (membership.php):

```
  //connecting to the SQL Select

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/PromoCode.mc.php");
  $mcPromoCode = new PromoCode_MC();

  // variable for the SQL Select

  $coupons3 = $mcPromoCode->SelectPromoCode($db);

  // isset for the redeem button

  if (isset($_POST['redeem']) && $_POST['redeem'] == 'REDEEM') {

    $couponCode = $_POST['lux_code'];

    // looping through the SQL select

    foreach($coupons3 as $coupons_db3) {

      if ($couponCode == $coupons_db3['coupon_code']) {
              echo $coupons_db3['coupon_code'];
              echo ' equal to ';
              echo $couponCode;
              ?><br><?php


           } else if ($couponCode != $coupons_db3['coupon_code']) {
             echo $coupons_db3['coupon_code'];
             echo ' not equal to ';
             echo $couponCode;
             ?><br><?php

           }
         }
  }
```

Please note that my echos are just for testing purposes only just to see if the comparisons in the foreach works.

There is supposed to be a comparison on the user input and the unused code in the database in "if ($couponCode == $coupons_db3['coupon_code'])" but it just goes straight to the "else".

Using that code right now, even if I enter an exact case-sensitive code in my input, it just goes through the "else" "not equal to" instead of "equal to".

[image: code]

In this example, I tried entering "MWCGB083" but it still says "not equal to" even if the user input and the unused code in the database is exactly the same.

Would like some help in what is wrong or missing in my comparison code. I have explained clearly what the issue is, thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: Have you checked for trailing or leading spaces in either the input or the database. Ensure when you insert into the database you `trim` http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php the result. Then when you take the user inputed code you `$couponCode = trim($_POST['lux_code']);`

Comment: Perhaps try using === instead of == for comparison

Comment: both === and trim does not change the output, all are still shown as not equal.

Comment: To add to @JasonBrumwell's comment, you need to use `trim($coupons_db3['coupon_code'])` just in case you have trailing spaces in the database. You could also change `echo $couponCode;` to `echo "'{$couponCode}'";`.  This will show if you have trailing spaces in the database.

Comment: Sometimes happen that there are "hidden characters" that you can't see but they're there. Maybe try also with escaping your strings so you can check that there is nothing weird inside them.

Comment: My first though is encoding, you may have some special stuff in one of them for example a `\0` null byte   [For Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a36869074b031983467d3f5fd08087a78d795ea5)  In some situations you will not be able to see them.  In your `MWCGB083 not equal to MWCGB083` Programming does't lie, something is different in one of them, you just can't see it.  In the example link, if you put the sand box in `raw` output and not `textarea` you won't be able to see the `\0`  but it's there and prevents the match,

Comment: I would try `trim` or `preg_replace('/[^[:priint:]]/','',$string)` both of which may remove it.  [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db2b91095b20ec0c8392e7635b1d827d96dad71e) you can see the above example with the addition of `trim`.  Not sure that is the case because well we can't see it, but its a possibility as I just proved.

Comment: Could you do `var_export` on your coupon codes and post the results?  Or check them for stuff that shouldn't be there.  Wouldn't hurt to do that on the form input, but it's more likely in the DB especially if these were imported from something like a CSV file etc.

Comment: Can you try run var_dump instead  of echo. This can give extra information if got extra character.

Answer (score 1):

Weird idea, but have you tried putting your logic in the query itself?

Fetching all the existing promo codes could lead to a lowered performance and/or even vulnerability issues.

(Untested, please let me know for any syntax errors, etc.)

```
public function VerifyPromoCode($db,$code) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    "   SELECT *
        FROM `promocode_3`
        WHERE code = ?
        AND used = 0
        ");

  $stmt->execute([$code]);
  if ($stmt->rowCount() >= 1) {
    //Promo code valid!
    return true;
  } else {
    //Promo code NOT valid
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use `LIKE %value%` for contains if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `trim` on them.  It's possible that you have some "extra" stuff in one of them like a null byte `\0`

You can see this with the below code.

```
$foo = "foo\0";  //<-- add a null byte

echo $foo." is ";;

var_dump('foo' == $foo);
var_dump('foo' == trim($foo));
```

Output (in raw mode, not the textarea in the sandbox):

```
foo is bool(false) bool(true)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db2b91095b20ec0c8392e7635b1d827d96dad71e)

Note the output does not show the null byte, and when comparing them it's not the same so here it's obviously false, but if we trim it then its the same and are true.

You can also try the nuclear option:

```
 $foo = preg_replace('/[*[:print:]]/', '', $foo);
```

What this does is remove all not-printable characters.  You can also use `var_export` which is designed to print syntactically correct values (when it can) for PHP, so you can paste them into code etc .. Something I wish more people on here would use, I even wrote a [converter](http://artisticphoenix.com/2018/11/11/output-converter/) for it.

Anywho:

```
  var_export($foo);
```

Output

```
  'foo' . "\0" . ''
```

I am not sure why it doesn't just do `"foo\0"` but whatever, I am sure syntax wise that would work.  But the point is, you see how it's now visible for debugging output.  Unfortunately you didn't paste the actual text in, sometimes even that can strip those out, depending how its handled.

Not sure if that is the reason, but as I show above it's possible.  The logic in programming just doesn't break down by itself.

Hope it helps!